# Django: How to transfer a html table from a template to a database table?

Tags: python, django

I have an HTML template (review.html) which gets populated dynamically with an HTML table. The table data can be changed by the user. After the user has made his changes, he then can save the whole table data to a Django database table by clicking a submit button.

[image: rom]

Here is the part where I need help: How can I insert the HTML table data into the database table? My goal is that all rows of the HTML table should be transferred to the database table when the user clicks the "save" button.

The database table exists in the Django models and all migrations are done. The HTML table has the same columns and column names as the database table, the datatypes are also the same. I just don't know how to write the function for the POST-request for the button click event.

The table can be modified by using this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table).

The data within the HTML table is plain text.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. How are you letting the user modify this table? What format is it in?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, you want to create a form out of a django database model.
[Helpful link](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/)

Please make the question clearer for further help!